# How to get stdinput and stderror with tee

Tags: linux, su, tee

With tee you can save the standard input, standard output and standard error to a file. I want to save all the standard input, output and error when I login to a user, but it's not working.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
$ su - username 2>&1 | tee -i /var/tmp/file.txt
```

It allow me to type the password but that's it.

Any idea why, options or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> With tee you can save the standard input, standard output and standard error to a file.

No - you can only save the (i. e. `tee`'s) standard input (which might be the standard output or standard error of another process) to a file.

What you want seems to be a *typescript of everything printed on your terminal*, so I suggest to use `script`:

```
script -c 'su - username' /var/tmp/file.txt
```